# Method to print MySQL row in PHP using foreach statement?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am new to `PHP` and programming, but am attempting to `print` out the results from each row of one of my `MySQL` `database` tables.

Using a set of `while` loops I achieved this:

```
while($placeHolder = $query->fetch_assoc()){ // use assoc
    echo "<div class='placeHolder'><img src=" . $placeHolder['photo']. " /></div>"; 
    echo "<br />";
}

while($placeHolder2 = $query2->fetch_assoc()){
    echo "<div class='placeHolder2'>" . $placeHolder2['name'] . "</div>"; 
    echo "<br />";
}

//etc, etc...
```

Besides being inefficient, I'm assuming this may also be a security risk.

Is there a better way to do this, possibly using a `foreach` statement?

Here is my SQL code I forgot to include:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);
$query2 = mysqli_query($conx, $sql);

$sql = ('SELECT id,name,picture FROM table ORDER BY name DESC LIMIT 50');
```

Comment: Are `$query2` and `$query` the same query (aside from the column being selected)? This could open you to XSS injections. Without the SQL we can't say if you are or aren't open to SQL injections.

Comment: Yes they are.  That is very interesting.  I will edit and show you the SQL.

Comment: You could do this with one fetch. Depending on how `photo` and `name` are assigned you might be open to XSS injections. Attributes also should be quoted. `src='"`.. `"'`

Comment: I'm confused, what do you mean depending on how photo and name are assigned?

Comment: If a user wrote the contents of `name` or `image` it could contain HTML/JS, which would execute. e.g. if `$placeHolder['photo']` contained `'/><script>alert('injected');</script>`. Then `injected would be alerted (if the `'` closed the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think using a foreach statement to print out the results would make it any less safe/unsafe.  It really depends on your query.  You should be able to print all of them using a foreach doing something like:

```
$result = $query->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($result as $row) {
     echo $row['photo'];
}
```

Note** to use fetch_all you would need [mysqlnd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqlnd.php) installed

edit: looking at your query nothing can be injected there.  No outside variables being used in the query, so its safe.  I would just use the while loop that you originally posted.

edit 2: link to fetch_all documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php